# Image-resizer powertoy for windows-7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec

I was looking for alternative of windows-xp powertoy "Image-resizer". I know many programs like irfanview,xnview can resize image. And many commercial applications can resize images as well.

But i was looking for small utlity which can embed itself into right click menu, and can work just like "image resizer" powertoy. is there any Image-resizer powertoy/utility clone for windows 7 ?

P:S - Unable to add link to Image resizer. SU is disabling links.  :-|

Comment: I take it the Image resizer power toy doesn't just work? I know there's no reason to assume it would, but Windows-7 isn't that far from XP.

Comment: PowerToys always only work on the exact operating system they were meant for. The installer cancels already. Although you probably can circumvent that somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**This**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phototoysclone/) "photo toy clone" works under Vista and 7:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I saw this linked on here somewhere before, but can't find the original post. Anyway, 
[Image Resizer 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/ImageResizer) is what you need.

> This is a clone of the Image Resizer
>   Powertoy for Windows XP -- a PowerToy
>   that allows you to right-click on one
>   or more image files in Windows
>   Explorer to resize them. This clone
>   was created to extend support to
>   non-XP and 64-bit versions of Windows
>   (including Windows 7 & Vista)